# Updating TimeStamp field a Slow Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login` (
  `eMail` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Password` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `UID` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `Text` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `OldText` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `LastSeen` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `SecurityQuestion` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `SecurityAnswer` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `eMail` (`eMail`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

When ever i try to update the `LastSeen` it shows as slow query [get logged into the slow query log file]
Can someone tell me whats wrong ?

A Sample SQL code [PHP]

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
UPDATE LOGIN set LastSeen=? WHERE UID=?
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"si",$time,$uid);
```

`Edit:`
I need the Timestamp cause i want to subtract current time with the data from the row. By default Timestam is automatically updated on each update, but it can be changed though [in my table the `LastSeen` filed is not automatically updated].

Comment: are you running the update comparing against UID?

Comment: Can you show us a typical query where you would update teh timestamp?

Comment: it does not take any time though, but the SQL logs in the slow_query log.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be updating a `timestamp` column: **timestamp columns are [automatically updated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) to the current time whenever you update the row**.

If you want an updatable "timestamp" column in mysql, use the `datetime` datatype.